# Can multiple Wavebird controllers hook up to one receiver?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-gamecube

I'm thinking of getting a Wavebird controller set. The set has two Wavebirds but only one receiver.

Is it possible to play a multiplayer game with two controllers to one receiver? I've never owned a Wavebird before, and I believe it would register one or both controllers as the same player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each receiver plugs into a single controller port, and can only be set to one channel. You will need a receiver for each controller that will be used simultaneously (and of course, set them to different channels).

Comment: Just curious: Is there another kind of receiver that will allow multiple controllers?

Comment: @BorWal: I honestly don't know. I wasn't aware of any such thing while the NGC was still popular, and the demand is too low to make anything recent profitable. Of course, it's entirely possible to homebrew such a receiver for other standards-based (e.g. Bluetooth) controllers.